# sql update statement including & and line break

Tags: php, sql, line-breaks, ampersand, sql-update

I'm using this update statement

```
$sql = "update questions set response = ?, `check` = ? where questionID = ? && starID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_GET['response'], $_GET['check'], $_GET['questionID'], $_SESSION['starid']));
```

But when the response value has an `&` in it, like `pop and r&b`, it ends up in the database as `pop and r`.

also if there is a line break it takes out all of the spaces, like:

```
Bob
Jim
```

ends up in the database as `BobJim`

The response type in the database is `varchar(10000)`

here is the javascript code that gets the `$_GET['response']` value

```
var html = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save_btn").live('click', function() {

        $('.response').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            //alert($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val() + "&check=0",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   
            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val($POST['response']) + "&check=1",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   

        }); 
        alert(html);
        location.reload();  
    });
})
```

this part of the if is the important part in this case:

```
       if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            html = $.ajax({
                url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val($POST['response']) + "&check=1",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
        }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should probably look at the actual value of your `$_GET` vars, that's probably where they are messed up.

Comment: for pop and r&b, echo $_GET['response']; = pop and r. tried post instead of get and got an empty value

Comment: so whatever is sending these variables through a GET request is not encoding them properly and that should be fixed first.

Comment: ok i'll edit my post to include that bit of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your value for URL:

```
escape($(this).val())
```

The `&` has a special meaning in a URL, it is used as a separator between paramaters.

Comment: like this: if ($(this).val() !== '') { html = $.ajax({ url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + escape($(this).val($POST['response'])) + "&check=1", async: false }).responseText; that makes echo $_POST['response'] not come up anymore
            }

Comment: @jenstar Shouldn't it be `escape($(this).val())`? Are you sure you are not mixing PHP and Javascript? `$(this).val($POST['response'])` is really weird.

Comment: i just took out the $_POST['response'] part so it's just escape($(this).val()) and now pop and r&b, using echo $_GET['response']; = pop and r&b. thanks it works now :-)